# counting the number of rdfs:label properties with NON-NULL values from DBpedia

Tags: count, sparql, dbpedia, rdfs

I need to count the number of rdfs:label properties with NON-NULL values from DBpedia.

I already have the total number of rdfs:label properties (NULL and NON-NULL values) from DBpedia using this query:

```
select (COUNT(*) as ?labelNum)
  WHERE { ?s rdfs:label ?o
}
```

I tried this query to get the rdfs:label with NULL values, but it returns 0:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?nullLabelNum)
  WHERE { ?s rdfs:label ?o
filter(isBlank(?o)) }
```

Comment: what means "non-null" in RDF? The absence of a triple? The absence of a label? And why should there be an `rdfs:label` triple with a blank node? That will not happen, the supposed value is a literal. So what are you trying to count?

Comment: @UninformedUser it means the absence of the object value (if the triple is ?s ?p ?o, there is no o, I wanna count how many triples which ?p=rdfs:label don't have an ?o)

Comment: that is not possible, not having an `?o` is impossible. In an RDF graph a triple is the basic unit of existence. You can't have nodes `?s` or tuples `?s ?p`  - if that's the case, then the triple is just not there at all. All you can do is to count the number of subjects that do not have such an `rdfs:label` edge at all. Think of a graph, either you have an edge between two nodes or not, but you won't have an edge outgoing from a node to nothing

Answer (score 0):

If an entity doesn’t have a value for `rdfs:label`, this entity can’t even *have* the `rdfs:label` property.

So your first query already counts how many `rdfs:label` values exist in the graph.

---

The [`isBlank`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-isBlank) from your second query checks if the value is a blank node, which is something that ideally doesn’t happen, because [`rdfs:label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_label) has `rdfs:Literal` as range (and blank nodes aren’t literals).

To only count `rdfs:label` values that are literals (which should be the case for all of them, barring errors), you can use [`isLiteral`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-isLiteral):

```
FILTER isLiteral(?o)
```

To exclude certain values from your count, e.g. the empty string, you could use

```
FILTER(?o != "")
```